# ActionView::Template::Error: Webpacker can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json when its deploy to the Gitlab using ci/cd autodevops

Tags: webpack, gitlab-ci, ruby-on-rails-6, gitlab-autodevops

It works perfect locally but receive this error during pipelines running with CI/CD in test stage when it's deployed to the Gitlab:

> ```
> Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError: Webpacker can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
> 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
> unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
> 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
> 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
> 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
> Your manifest contains:
> {
> }
> ```
>
> Here are few lines from the application.html file:
>
> ```
> <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
> <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
> ```
>
> and my stylesheets are .scss files and there's no .css file in the project.
>
> This is my webpacker.yml :
>
> ```
> default: &default
>   source_path: app/javascript
>   source_entry_path: packs
>   public_root_path: public
>   public_output_path: packs
>   cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
>   check_yarn_integrity: false
>   webpack_compile_output: true
>
>   # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
>   # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
>   resolved_paths: [ ]
>
>   # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
>   cache_manifest: false
>
>   # Extract and emit a css file
>   extract_css: true
>
>   static_assets_extensions:
>     - .jpg
>     - .jpeg
>     - .png
>     - .gif
>     - .tiff
>     - .ico
>     - .svg
>     - .eot
>     - .otf
>     - .ttf
>     - .woff
>     - .woff2
>
>   extensions:
>     - .mjs
>     - .js
>     - .sass
>     - .scss
>     - .css
>     - .module.sass
>     - .module.scss
>     - .module.css
>     - .png
>     - .svg
>     - .gif
>     - .jpeg
>     - .jpg
>
> development:
>   <<: *default
>   compile: true
>
>   # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
>   check_yarn_integrity: true
>
>   # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
>   dev_server:
>     https: false
>     host: localhost
>     port: 3035
>     public: localhost:3035
>     hmr: false
>     # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
>     inline: true
>     overlay: true
>     compress: true
>     disable_host_check: true
>     use_local_ip: false
>     quiet: false
>     pretty: false
>     headers:
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
>     watch_options:
>       ignored: "**/node_modules/**"
>
> test:
>   <<: *default
>   compile: true
>
>   # Compile test packs to a separate directory
>   public_output_path: packs-test
>
> production:
>   <<: *default
>
>   # Production depends on the precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
>   compile: false
>
>   # Extract and emit a css file
>   extract_css: true
>
>   # Cache manifest.json for performance
>   cache_manifest: true
> ```
>
> Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3):

For easy solution;
Create `app/javascript/stylesheets` folder and add in that folder empty `application.scss` file

after open `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file and import added file to your pack js file with;

```
import '../stylesheets/application';
```

Let webpacker compile again all files with css/scss file.

Comment: I guess you mean `rails webpacker:compile` for the later sentence?